# How to use Group By in a D365FO data entity

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm creating a data entity with multiple tables and I'm getting duplicate results. Because of the nature of the duplicates, I thought an easy solution would be to add the relevant fields to the Group By section in the primary datasource. However, when I run the entity as a data project in the DMF, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Has anybody run into this before and how do I resolve it? I've tried adding the RecId to the group by (even though it shouldn't even be in the select list as it is not in the field list for the entity). I have noticed that adding fields to the Group By section changes the view in SQL and removes all of the RecId#2, Partitian#2 etc. fields. Does the Group By section even work or is it a broken "feature"?

[image]

The entity works perfectly (other than with duplicate results of course) when I remove all fields from the group by section.

UPDATE: From what I can find online, the group by functionality doesn't work. I'll update this question if somebody finds an answer. I am lucky this was an XML export, so I was able to use a XSLT file in the transformations under data entity mapping to remove duplicates.

Comment: I see two `RecId` fields in your image (middle and bottom), is that what you intended?

Comment: I added them to the group by for testing and forgot when I took the screenshot. With or without them it makes no difference; the error persists.